# ios parent View block display of Scroll View

Tags: ios, xcode, scrollview

I'm new to ios development. Trying to figure out scroll view. I've watched several posts and video tuts and followed the settings. But one annoying thing keeps happening, which is that the content of Scroll View could not show up at all.
[Constraint settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUTJg.png)

For testing, I set BG color of Parent View, Scroll View and Content View to be different. It turns out that only Parent View shows up. Scroll View never shows itself.

Any hints about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question with relevant code trails.

Comment: UIScrollView has 6 (not 4) needed constrain. You should add 6 constraint for scrollview (left-right-top-bottom-width-height)